# Error in get JSON Data in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift4

[image: my data from server is not loading in my tableview and is giving me this error from server]

My JSON looks like this and data is not coming from the server:

```
[
    {
        "emp_id": "1",
        "fname": "Shreya",
        "lname": "Shah",
        "email_id": "shreyashah@gmail.com",
        "password": "shreya123",
        "date_of_birth": "14/03/1995",
        "gender": "Female",
        "street1": "Arbudgiri Society",
        "street2": "Nr.Rambaug Road",
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "zipcode": "380005",
        "country": "India",
        "country_code": "+91",
        "phone_no": "456544545",
        "emp_img": "employeeImages/shreyashah@gmail.com_services-pic2.jpg",
        "emp_desig": "PHP Developer",
        "emp_skills": "html,php,css,jquery,javascript",
        "emp_edu": "BCA,MCA",
        "emp_exp": "3years",
        "emp_notice_period": "30days",
        "emp_lang": "english,hindi,gujarati"
    },
    {
        "emp_id": "2",
        "fname": "Harish",
        "lname": "Verma",
        "email_id": "harishverma@gmail.com",
        "password": "harish123",
        "date_of_birth": "22/07/1994",
        "gender": "Female",
        "street1": "Satyam Skyline",
        "street2": "Nr.Sola Cross Roads",
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "zipcode": "380005",
        "country": "India",
        "country_code": "+91",
        "phone_no": "964783214",
        "emp_img": "employeeImages/harishverma@gmail.com_services-pic2.jpg",
        "emp_desig": "iOS Team Lead",
        "emp_skills": "objective-c,swift",
        "emp_edu": "BCA,MCA",
        "emp_exp": "3years",
        "emp_notice_period": "30days",
        "emp_lang": "english,hindi,gujarati"
    }
]
```

My code in VIEWCONTROLLER code where i have decoded the json and used it in my file:

```
import UIKit


struct EmployeeDisplayData: Decodable {
    let emp_img: String
    let fname: String
    let emp_desig: String
    let emp_exp: String
    let country: String
    let emp_notice_period: String
}

class UserViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!

    let URL_GET_DATA = "http://172.16.1.22/Get-Employee-API/get-employee/"


    var employeeArray = [EmployeeDisplayData]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mainTableView.delegate = self
        self.mainTableView.dataSource = self
        getEmployee()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func getEmployee(){
        let empURL = URL(string: "http://172.16.1.22/Get-Employee-API/get-employee/")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: empURL!) { (data, response, error) in
            do
            {
                if error == nil
                {
                    self.employeeArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([EmployeeDisplayData].self, from: data!)

                    for mainArr in self.employeeArray
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.mainTableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    print("****Employee Data****\(self.employeeArray)")
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error in get JSON Data Employee\(error)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return employeeArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:EMpTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EMpTableViewCell") as! EMpTableViewCell
        let empData = employeeArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblOne.text = empData.fname
        cell.lblTwo.text = empData.emp_desig
        cell.lblThree.text = empData.emp_exp
        return cell 
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

}
```

Can someone help me with this error I have no idea what does this error mean I have seen the same type error most of the places and tried to solve it but still the same error from the server

my postman [image: My postman looks like this]

[image: Raw View of it[![Preview view of it]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUNpn.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is improper json response from the server.

Comment: @bbarnhart, It's your Personal opinion that this question is **off-topic** but as per my and some other users opinion it's valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same error and I searched a lot by changing `contentType` and many more things but none is fixed it. `PostMan` **Raw** and **Preview** Tab response gives me idea where the exact issue.

**Raw**
[image]

**Preview**
[image]

This error occur because of **Connected to MySQL** text beginning of response. so inform your developer about this, he will solve this and may be the error solve.

Comment: @AudreyRozario, If this answer helps you that you can accept this.

Comment: Hello Kuldeep can you help me with my new question

Comment: Hello Kuldeep can you help my friend with her question Here's the link---->>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448806/on-cell-click-display-image-of-particular-logged-in-id

Comment: @AudreyRozario, update your API response in question.

Comment: @AudreyRozario, in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448806/on-cell-click-display-image-of-particular-logged-in-id

Comment: @AudreyRozario, yes