# On cell click display image of particular logged in id

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I need to print image in my next view controller after comparing ID of a table containing user details after comparing the ID I am successfully getting the name but the respective image is unable to fetch
if the user has posted anything then I am getting name for particular posted job now what I want is image of from respective user (that image which user uploaded while registration), (which identifies the posted job is posted via which user).

[image: Job Response from Postman]
[image: Company Response from Postman]

Below is my code:

```
func getJOBData()
    {
        let jobUrl = URL(string: "http://172.16.1.22/Get-Job-API/get-jobs/")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jobUrl!) { (data, response, error) in

            do
            {
                if error == nil
                {
                    self.jobArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([JobData].self, from: data!)

                    for mainJobArr in self.jobArray
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.jobPostTblView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    print("Job Data****\(self.jobArray)")
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                //                print("my data=\(self.mainCellData)")
                print("Error in get JSON Data\(error)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return jobFilteredArray.count
        }
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath Method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("JobTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! JobTableViewCell

            let data = jobArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.jobTitle.text = data.job_desig
            cell.expDetails.text = data.job_exp_to
            cell.locationDetails.text = data.job_location
            cell.dateDetails.text = data.job_skills
            cell.companyName.text = companyArray.first { $0.company_id == data.company_id }?.company_name

return cell

        }
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
                let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
                selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                let rows = indexPath.row
                print("Rows=\(rows)")
                let jobDetail = WorkerJobDetailsViewController(nibName: "WorkerJobDetailsViewController", bundle: nil)

                let jdata = jobFilteredArray[indexPath.row]
                jobDetail.gender = jobArray[indexPath.row].job_emp_gender
                jobDetail.location = jobArray[indexPath.row].job_location
                jobDetail.companyName = (companyArray.first { $0.company_id == jdata.company_id }?.company_name)!

                jobDetail.profile = jobImgPath
                jobImgPath = (companyArray.first { $0.company_id == jdata.company_id }?.company_logo)!

                jobDetail.skills = jobArray[indexPath.row].job_skills
                jobDetail.descriptionValue = jobArray[indexPath.row].job_desc
                jobDetail.jobDesignation = jobArray[indexPath.row].job_desig

                self.present(jobDetail, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

Can anyone please help me to fetch images for respective user of posted job??

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Yes please thank you for pointing my mistakes can you please help me to improve them?

Answer (score 0):

just use a pod like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and fetch the link with the url that you are mapping the problem that you will face is that the link is a local ip and it will not work from a remote network but if the link changes at the json in the future you will be fine

Without pod you can do this

```
    func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        completion(data, response, error)
    }.resume()
    }

    func downloadImage(url: URL) {
    print("Download Started")
    getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        print("Download Finished")
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Do I have to write both the functions in same file and call them in viewDidLoad() ??

Comment: You do have to write both functions and you call them when you want to load the picture if you want to have it loaded in the beginning yes in view did load, it will run asynchronous so it might delay to fetch the pic but it will, if you want to notify the user that a picture is being downloading you can show an activity indicator but from now all you have to do is to call the function when you want

Comment: what should I have to write over here? downloadImage(url: (?))

Comment: I had changed it already as per my imageView, like this  self.profileInage.image = UIImage(data: data)

Comment: Now I am confused about  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad(
        downloadImage(url: ) what should I have to pass as url in this method??

Comment: No.. you don't pass it as a parameter on super.. 

you call the function

Comment: If you first need to fetch the json you will have to wait until the fetch happens, one way to do this is to create DispatchGroup() but ject it that it works and that's another issue

Comment: @JuhiDanak, I think both of your array are of NSObject type right? If yes that you need to filter jobArray company_id in jobFilteredArray so you get only matched record and from that object you can get image url.

Comment: @Kuldeep thanks, for your guidance but, just now I had solved my issue by correcting my code..once again thank you..!